# Difference between <React.Fragment> vs <>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to know the difference between <React.Fragment> versus <> in terms of the efficiency?

Comment: It`s transformed during transpile to a fragment, so it's the same runtime code, But like mentioned the transform does not handle keys.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is mostly same, with main difference:

> You can use <></> the same way you’d use any other element except that
> it doesn’t support keys or attributes.

[More](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

---

About efficiency, IMHO there should be no difference, at least it is not documented.

Here is brief experiment, using `Test1` or `Test2` inside `Main` gives same performance more or less, if  you check using React Profiler:

```
let array = [...new Array(1000)];

let Test1 = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>b</div>
    </>
  );
};

let Test2 = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <div>b</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

let Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((x) => (
        <Test2 />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<></>` syntax is shorthand of `<React.Fragment>` with a little difference.
you Can't pass **key** or **attributes** to `<>`

```js
someArray.map(item => (
        // Without the `key`, React will fire a key warning
        <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <dt>{item.term}</dt>
          <dd>{item.description}</dd>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))
```

The above example is not possible with `<>`

[Check react docs for more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

It is the same thing. The `<>` is just a [short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax).

Comment: Yes, however the <> syntax does not support attributes.

Comment: @Petros true, although the only key the `Fragment` supports is `key`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those will be "mapped" to exactly the same thing in the end. So IMHO there is no difference in efficiency.